# How to get error from preparedstatement for inserting from JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am using  PreparedStatement in JDBC to insert records. I set up a unique index on the table. When I run the sql against mysql db from console, I got the following error as expected

```
Duplicate entry 'val1-val2' for key 'some_unique_key_idx'
```

But when I run the same from JDBC. I don't see any error reported, although the result returned is "0" which means nothing got inserted. Is there anyway to get the Duplicate entry error?

Comment: Would it be possible to see the java code that you are running the statement with. This does not sound right.

Comment: You are right. Someone is using INSERT IGNORE INTO.... for some reason